# Подключение сторонней библиотеки к мавен-проекту (Java)

Tags: java, maven, junit

Есть написанная игра на Java. Я создал мавен-проект, перенес туда все файлы, сделано это для написания юнит-тестов. Все работает, игра запускается.

Есть библиотека desktop-game-engine.jar, лежит в пакете .lib, и очень любит мне мозг.

Структура проекта следующая:

[image: структура]

Пишу тест, компилирую через мавен, и IDEA выдает следующее:

[image: ошибка]

Добавил desktop-game-engine.jar в Project Structure - Libraries , сделал ее глобальной библиотекой, добавлял Modules- Dependencies, кидал в SDK,  - ничего не помогает.

Как сделать, чтобы IDEA видела эту библиотеку и не говорила, что путь до нее не существует?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: а есть способ не устанавливая maven вручную, решить проблему?

Comment: в src добавляете папку META-INF туда добавляете файл MANIFEST.MF в котором прописываете - Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . lib\desktop-game-engine.jar
 r
Main-Class: RacerGame

Comment: мне нужно переместить библиотеку (папку lib c содержимым) в папку java?

Comment: нет, должна лежать там где лежит сейчас

Comment: Вылезла ошибка при создании заглушки (mock-a): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/javarush/engine/cell/Game ... Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: а это к чему? Закоментите тест пока )))

Comment: После всех действий с манифестом тесты Junit стали проходить, но тесты mockito выкидывают вышенаписанную ошибку. Вот и спрашиваю, это связано как-то или нужно копать в другом направлении?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022219/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-objenesis-objenesisstd-with-mockito

Comment: Это не то, но на главный вопрос вы мне ответили) Спасибо! Как отметить, что это ответ?

Comment: Отметьте как ответ в моем посте ответов ниже, по поводу теста - лучше создать отдельный вопрос ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в src добавляете папку META-INF туда добавляете файл MANIFEST.MF в котором прописываете -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Class-Path:
.lib\desktop-game-engine.jar
Main-Class: RacerGame
```